# The process hangs in SQL: State "Writing to net"

Tags: mysql

Tell me what this problem may be related to

query: SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `tblLogs`;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n0GB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Taking this in two parts:

This ...

```
/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */
```

... is a directive telling mysql *not* to use the SQL Query [Plan] Cache.
This option is deprecated in newer versions of mysql and I doubt it's your problem.

What's left is this ...

```
SELECT * FROM tblLogs;
```

... and this tells mysql to read *everything* in tblLogs and send it back to the client.
Whether there's *one* row or, more likely, *millions* of rows, regardless of how many columns there are on each row or what Data Types those columns are, mysql will read the whole lot and shove it down the network cable, back to the client.

If there's any kind of network bottleneck or slow-down, this query will suffer hugely from it.
(And it's another demonstration of why you shouldn't use `select *` in Production code).